# if statement inside an array creation ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I am trying to do a if statement inside a array creation

```
markers_index = Array.new        
@events.each_with_index do |event, index|
...

        markers_index << {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [event.longitude, event.latitude]
          },
          properties: {
            markerurl: event.photo.marker.url,
            divclass: marker_class,
            if has_popup
              popupContent: marker_popup
            end
          }
        }
    end
```

But it throws me a syntax error

**unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
              popupContent: 'marker_popup'**

Is it a typo or I simply can't do this and need to repeat the whole thing wrapping it in a if else wrapping my marker_index variable ? Trying to stay DRY..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instance :

```
h= {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [event.longitude, event.latitude]
  },
  properties: {
    markerurl: event.photo.marker.url,
    divclass: marker_class,
  }
}
if has_popup
  h[:properties][:popupContent]= marker_popup
end
markers_index << h
```

Comment: that was fast, thank you ! any reading suggestion regarding arrays ?

Answer (score 1):

```
h= {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [event.longitude, event.latitude]
  },
  properties: {
    markerurl: event.photo.marker.url,
    divclass: marker_class,
  }.tap { |g| g[:popupContent] = marker_popup if has_popup }
}
```

See [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap).

Comment: Or `g.merge!(popupContent: marker_popup)` if you want to keep the hash syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to doing the if conditional after the Hash creation as someone else mentioned, you can also only populate the value of your hash Key/Val pair if the statement evaluates to true. Then you just test if the value is nil to act/not act on it later on using the ternary operator (condition ? if true : if false):

```
markers_index = Array.new        
@events.each_with_index do |event, index|
...

        markers_index << {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [event.longitude, event.latitude]
          },
          properties: {
            markerurl: event.photo.marker.url,
            divclass: marker_class,
            popupContent: has_popup ? marker_popup : nil
          }
        }
    end
```